# F#: How to Access a Dotnet Object's Method's Specific Overload as a First Class-object

Tags: function, f#, overloading, first-class

I can do this (F# FSI):

```
let o = Object()
let m = o.GetHashCode;; //[1]
val o : Object
val m : (unit -> int)
```

which makes method `GetHashCode` accessible and callable as a first-class function in binding `m`:

```
m ();;
val it : int = 12345678
```

How would I go about doing this if there existed an overload for the method in question, say an additional `Object.GetHashCode(int whateverParameter)`? I now can only get the 'first' (shortest?) method. Can I provide extra parameter type information in call [1](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) to specify which overload I desire?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your input so far. Type annotations seem the way to go. Albeit, for my more complicated example I still cannot figure out how to correctly do that.

Here are the concrete method signatures from the type I am dealing with (it comes from the [octokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) library, so you need something like `#r "nuget:include=Octokit"` in your fsi [with `/langversion:preview`]).

I am interested in retrieving a specific overload of `GetAllForRepository`, incidentally the first one listed: `GetAllForRepository(string, string)`.

```
open Octokit
let client = GitHubClient(...)
client.Issue.GetType().GetMethods()
|> Seq.filter (fun methodInfo -> methodInfo.Name.StartsWith("GetAllForRepository"))
|> Seq.map (fun methodInfo -> (methodInfo.GetParameters(), methodInfo.ReturnType))
|> Seq.map (fun (parameterInfos, returnType) ->
    (parameterInfos |> Seq.map (fun parameterInfo -> parameterInfo.ParameterType.FullName), returnType.FullName))

val it : seq<seq<string> * string> =
  seq
    [(seq ["System.String"; "System.String"],
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Octokit.Issue, Octokit, Version=0.48.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]");
     (seq ["System.Int64"],
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Octokit.Issue, Octokit, Version=0.48.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]");
     (seq ["System.String"; "System.String"; "Octokit.ApiOptions"],
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Octokit.Issue, Octokit, Version=0.48.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]");
     (seq ["System.Int64"; "Octokit.ApiOptions"],
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Octokit.Issue, Octokit, Version=0.48.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]");
     (seq ["System.String"; "System.String"; "Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest"],
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Octokit.Issue, Octokit, Version=0.48.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]");
     (seq ["System.Int64"; "Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest"],
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Octokit.Issue, Octokit, Version=0.48.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]");
     (seq
        ["System.String"; "System.String"; "Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest";
         "Octokit.ApiOptions"],
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Octokit.Issue, Octokit, Version=0.48.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]");
     (seq
        ["System.Int64"; "Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest";
         "Octokit.ApiOptions"],
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[Octokit.Issue, Octokit, Version=0.48.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]")]
```

Now, the 'shortest' signature takes one `int64` parameter:

```
let m = client.Issue.GetAllForRepository;;
val m :
  (int64 ->
     System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>)
```

I can explicitly declare the signature and receive the same method:

```
let m: (int64 -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>) = client.Issue.GetAllForRepository;;
val m :
  (int64 ->
     System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>)
```

But accessing the `(string, string)` version gives me:

```
let m: (string -> string -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>) = client.Issue.GetAllForRepository;;

  let m: (string -> string -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>) = client.Issue.GetAllForRepository;;
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(33,117): error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type
    'string'
is not compatible with type
    'int64'
```

Similar error occur when trying to access any other overload with more than one parameter:

```
let m: (int64 -> Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>) = client.Issue.GetAllForRepository;;

  let m: (int64 -> Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>) = client.Issue.GetAllForRepository;;
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(37,140): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>'
but here has type
    'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>'
```

```
let m: (int64 -> Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest -> Octokit.ApiOptions -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>) = client.Issue.- GetAllForRepository;;

  let m: (int64 -> Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest -> Octokit.ApiOptions -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>) = client.Issue.GetAllForRepository;;
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(36,162): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'Octokit.RepositoryIssueRequest -> Octokit.ApiOptions -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>'
but here has type
    'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>'
```

So, am I doing something wrong with regard to the type annotations?

Comment: When I try to assign a method with an overload to a variable I get the suggestion *"A type annotation may be needed."* - did you try doing just that?

Comment: @Christian Welcome to the F# community!

Comment: This indeed works for simple cases, like `let m: char -> int = "Hello".IndexOf;;`, chosing `System.String.IndexOf(char)` over `System.String.IndexOf(string)`. But the signatures of my intended methods (from the octokit.net library) are more complicated, like `Task<IReadOnlyList<Issue>> GetAllForRepository(string owner, string name)`. Perhaps it's due to the `Task<...>` return value.

Comment: Have you tried `m: ((string * string) -> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Octokit.Issue>>)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your edit, the method's input is `string * string`, not `string -> string` (i.e. uncurried vs. curried), so I think this will work:

```
let m : (string * string -> _) = client.Issue.GetAllForRepository
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you all, but specifically @brianberns for helping me with my specific stupidity!

Comment: Not stupid at all. Currying takes a while to get used to. Happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a type annotation will allow you to select the method override that you want:

```
type MyClass() =
    member __.MyMethod() = 1
    member __.MyMethod(x : int) = 2

let o = MyClass()
let m1 : (unit -> int) = o.MyMethod
let m2 : (int -> int) = o.MyMethod
printfn "%A" <| m1 ()
printfn "%A" <| m2 0
```

Comment: Thanks @brianberns. This works for 'simple' cases, unfortunately not for my real-world example. I have expanded the original question.